# How to format a date to always show as UTC

Tags: javascript, timestamp

I am trying to format a date such that it always shows as UTC e.g. in the format 'dd/mm/YYYY HH:MM UTC'. So far I have this code:

```
const options = {
    year: 'numeric',
    month: 'numeric',
    day: 'numeric',
    hour: 'numeric',
    minute: 'numeric',
    timezone: 'UTC',
    timeZoneName: 'short'
};

const formattedTime = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB', options).format(new Date(unixTimestamp))
```

However this gives me a time in either GMT or BST, e.g.

```
24/11/2021, 05:51 GMT
27/10/2021, 05:09 BST
```

What I would like is for the time to be always shown as UTC so in the case of the above examples:

```
24/11/2021, 05:51 UTC
27/10/2021, 04:09 UTC
```

Is there a way to configure DateTimeFormat to do this or should I be using something else? I'd rather not resort to importing a library if at all possible.

Comment: "timezone" must be in CamelCase - `timeZone`

Comment: @IVOGELOV Excellent and well spotted. Add as a an answer I will mark as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `timezone` property of the formatting options object must be in camelCase - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat#timezone